# Rotate Tool keeps rotating the specified path as well in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, transform

Trying to use the Rotate Tool to move a rectangle AROUND a circle.

Instead both the rectangle and circle rotate.

How do I stop this from moving? The circle should be fixed in its position.

**Before Rotate Tool:**
[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Actual Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause of problem is Handle**

It seems you didn't centralized your Rotation handle therefore it will rotate around Axes of current handle basically when you merge paths or group paths handle doesn't stay in perfect center and it changes to center of bound so before rotating make sure you allign your Handle to center :) Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: Hi @design-phoenix, thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention I'm trying to rotate the circle with the "Rotate Tool Options" instead of directly rotating on the circle itself. The rotation handle automatically reinitalizes to the combined centre of the selection (instead of just the circle) when I double-click the Rotate Tool on the toolbar. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: it's default behaviour so it can't be changed but you have workaround for that.just double click on circle once you select or right click and select Isolate path or shape. once in isolation mode the default will be resetted and the handle will be in center. press esc to exit isolation mode

Comment: @cdpp You can alt click to move the center and that opens the options dialog with the center where you clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use the Transform **Effect**.

Simple extend the rectangle so the bottom of it is flush with the center of the circle.

Select only the rectangle and choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`

In the **Transform** dialog window, tick the **bottom center** for the **origin point** (and tick "preview") and then rotate all you want.

You can then leave the effect as a live effect which you can adjust later if needed.

Or you can choose `Object > Expand Appearance` to "bake in" the rotation.

[image]

You can also use the **Transform Panel** and `Undo`...

Again extend the rectangle so the bottom is flush with the center of the circle. Set the **origin point** on the **Transform Panel** to the bottom center and enter a value in the rotate field and tap <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd>. If the rotation is incorrect, `Edit > Undo` and try again.

You can only enter 1 rotation step and then you need to `Undo` because after each rotation the bottom center origin is *different* based upon the last rotation.

[image]

I find these methods work better for me. I dislike trying to hunt and peck for the exact center of things with the rotate tool. Smart Guides make it easier, but using the Effect allows me to alter later if I want. Unless they've altered things in the last release, the Rotate Tool won't honor the 9-point origin setting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to select rectangle with white arrow which will make circle unselected, then set rotation center in the circle center and then you will get only rectangle rotation.